# Initialize a class object inside the other class constructor

Tags: c++, class

I am new to C++. Well I have  box.cpp and circle.cpp files. Before I explain my problem I'd like to give you their definitions:

In box.cpp

```
  class Box
  {
       private:
       int area;

       public:
       Box(int area);
       int getArea() const;

  }
```

In circle.cpp

```
   #include "box.h"
   class Circle
   {
      private:
      int area;
      Box box;

      public:
      Circle(int area, string str);
      int getArea() const;
      const Box& getBoxArea() const;  

   }
```

Now as you can see in the Circle class I have an integer value and Box object. And in Circle constructor I assign that integer values easily to area.

One problem is that I am given a string for  assigning it to the Box object

So what I did inside the Circle constructor is that:

```
 Circle :: Circle(int area, string str)
 {
  this->area = area;
  // here I convert string to an integer value
  // Lets say int_str;
  // And later I assign that int_str to Box object like this:
    Box box(int_str);

 }
```

My  intention is to access both Circle area value and Circle object area value.
And Finally I write the function const Box& getBoxArea() const; Like this:

```
  const Box& getBoxArea() const
  {
       return this->box;    
  }
```

And as a result I do not get the correct values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code should not even compile. `Box` would need a default constructor. Please post some realistic code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [initializing a object in an another class object .(after doing some operations on that constructor.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345054/initializing-a-object-in-an-another-class-object-after-doing-some-operations-o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest writing a non-member function that calculated the `int` based on the input string, and then use that in `Circle`'s constructor initialization list.

```
std::string foo(int area) { .... }
```

then

```
Circle :: Circle(int area, string str) : box(foo(str)) { .... }
```

You can only *initialize* a non-static data member in the initialization list. Once you get into the constructor body, everything has been initialized for you and all you can do is perform modifications to the data members. So one variant of your code which would compile if `Box` had a default constructor would be

```
Circle :: Circle(int area, string str) : area(area)
{
  // calculate int_str
  ....
  box = Box(int_str);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a default constructor? I think I already have a Box constructor in first file

Comment: @user2878007 you have a constructor `Box(int);`. A default constructor has no parameters: `Box();`

Answer (score 5):

In constructor of `Circle` you are trying to create an instance of `Box`, which is too late because by the time the body of constructor will be executed, the members of `Circle` shall be constructed already. Class `Box` either needs a default constructor or you need to initialize `box` in an initialization list:

```
Box constructBoxFromStr(const std::string& str) {
    int i;
    ...
    return Box(i);
}

class Circle
{
private:
    int area;
    Box box;

public:
    Circle(int area, string str)
      : area(area), box(constructBoxFromStr(str)) { }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I see but the problem is that I don't have a default constructor

Comment: @user2878007: The solution I pointed out doesn't require a default constructor.