# Can I initialize a class in another class?

Tags: c++, class

I am working on a scrabble project.  In the project I have a class for tiles that contains an int value for both the score of the letter and for the count of the tiles there are in the game.  This is the _tile class.

The other class in my code is the tile_pool class.  It is supposed to have 27 tile classes for the 26 letters and the blank tile.  Unfortunately when I compile my code, I always get the "error: expected identifier before numeric constant".

```
class Tile {
    int count;
    int score;
    public:
    _tile(int , int );
};

_tile::_tile(int _count = 0, int _score = 0): count(_count) , score(_score) {
}

class Pool{
    Tile A(9,1); 
    ... (the rest of the letters)
};
```

I looked around and found [Initialize a class object inside the other class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355857/initialize-a-class-object-inside-the-other-class-constructor)
so I tried making a default constructor for the _tile object but that didn't change the error.  I also found that when I take line 14 and put it in my main function, there are no issues.  I also tried initializing the Tile first and then having a set_values function to set the count and score for a tile, but that didn't work either.

```
void set_values(int _count, int _score) {
    count = _count;
    score = _score;
}
```

And in the tile_pool function:

```
Tile A;
A.set_values(9,1);
```

That returned the "error: ‘A’ does not name a type"

I don't understand why I can't initialize a Tile in my tile_pool class but I can in my main.  Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the answers!  I edited the code to follow guidelines better and changed the way I declared my classes as suggested.  I also changed my solution to:

```
class Pool {
    Tile a = Tile(9,1);
};
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Without line numbers. Also `typedef class _tile { ... } Tile;` is a C-ism, in C++ we write `class Tile { ... };`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
Tile A = Tile(9,1);
```

or

```
Tile A{9, 1};
```

You probably want these to be `static const` because you only need one master tile for all instances of the class.  (In fact this is a bad design entirely but you'll figure that out for yourself after a while).

---

BTW `typedef class...` is poor style, you should just write `class Tile` (or whatever you want to call your class). There is no need to have 2 names for the same class.  Also, it is unconventional to use leading underscore (`_tile`) in a class name.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class Pool {
    Tile A; 
public:
    Pool() : A(9, 1) {}
};
```